# How do I select all non-NaN data from a specific column of a mxn array in as few steps as possible?

Tags: matlab

So if it's just a 1D vector, I can simply do something like this:

y1 = y(~isnan(y));

But... What if y is a mxn matrix and I want all non-NaN data from y(:,5)? What can I then do, that takes as few extra steps as possible?

I can assign y1 = y(:,5) and then call y1 = y(~isnan(y)). But I'd prefer to avoid assigning too many new variables if possible.

Comment: Did you try the above code for a matrix?

Comment: It then collapses all the data points into a single vector (destroying the vector's structure). I wonder if there is a way to do it without destroying its structure?

Comment: But how else could it work?  You can't have a matrix with "holes" in it.  What kind of result are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no new variables, you just filter the data from the 5-th column with non-nan values from the fifth column. Duplicated, I know.

```
y(~isnan(y(:,5)),5)
```

As for not changing the shape. I believe if initialized as a nx1 matrix and assigned indices, it should retain shape.

```
y_nonnan(:,1) = y(~isnan(y(:,5)),5)
```

I just can't remember any elegant ways to make a nx1 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

> But... What if y is a mxn matrix and I want all non-NaN data from y(:,5)? What can I then do, that takes as few extra steps as possible?

You could use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), but doing so without any intermediate variables would still be seriously ugly.  My suggestion would be to write a function that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the coordinates of the non Nan elements of y you can use the following:

```
[row col]=ind2sub(size(y),find(~isnan(y)));
```